# Prove that both sequences converge to the same limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let ${a_n}$ be a monotonic decreasing sequence.
and Let ${b_n}$ be a monotonic increasing sequence.

Its given that for each $n:$
 $$b_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_nb_n}$$

Prove that both sequences converge to the same limit.

by doing some algebra, using the fact that: $a_{n+1}\le a_n$ and $b_n \le b_{n+1}$ I got that the following inequality:

$b_n \le b_{n+1} \le a_{n+1} \le a_n$.

now in order to prove that $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge to the same limit I thought about using the Lemma of Cantor. but there is one thing else that I need to prove first, which is that: $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ $(a_n - b_n)=0$.

do you guys have any hints for how to do that?

Comment: Presumably you mean strict when talking about increasing/decreasing.If not, then $a_n = 1$, $b_n = 0$ would be a solution.

Comment: Or at least positive. @copper.hat

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes I am certain about that :-).

Comment: Thomas' comment contains a key element, that is, at least one $b_n >0$ (and hence all from there on). (I find it remarkably difficult to make a brief, mathematically correct statement.)

Comment: @copper.hat yes, but Im not trying to find $a_n$ and $b_n$, i'm trying to prove in general, and that its true for every two sequences with the same qualities.

Comment: I understand. But without appropriate assumptions you cannot prove what you want to prove. If you do not have some way of ensuring that at least one $b_n$ is strictly positive, then the example in my comment is a counterexample. So, as @ThomasAndrews comment suggests, if there is at least one $b_n>0$, then the limit is strictly positive. Then you can find the desired answer from his answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$a_n=\frac{b_{n+1}^2}{b_n}$$

Since you know $b_n$ converges, what is the limit of the right side?

Comment: But Op hasnot said, $b_n$ converges

Comment: Yes he has - he knows it is increasing and shown it is bounded above. @RaziehNoori

Comment: oh, you are right, thank you.

Comment: Ok, now I noticed that $b_n$ is bounded from above and monotonic increasing, then it converges to its supremum. which is $a_{n+1}$, but how do I calculate the of the right side where I got no numbers at all, I got the limit of $b_n$ as a description of $a_n$.

Comment: No, $a_{n+1}$ is not the supremum of $b_n$. You only know that all $a_k$ are an upper bound for $b_1,\dots,b_n,\dots$, not that $a_k$ is a least upper bound (supremum.) @F1sargyan

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ok, lets suppose that $b_{n}$ Converges to $L$ then the right side converges to $f

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ok , lets suppose that $b_n$ converges to $L$, then the right side converges to $\frac{L^2}{L}$ which is L, same limit of $a_n$, is it right ? \

Comment: If $b_n \to L$ then $b_{n+1}^2 \to L$.

Comment: @copper.hat Um, typo?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: See my 3rd comment to the question :-). You are correct, of course, I meant $b_{n+1}^2 \to L^2$.